# Ruby: Convert String to Symbol during String Interpolation

Tags: ruby

I am looping over a block of code, each time increasing variable "filter_index", from 1, to 2, to 3... etc.

I'd like to use this variable to access the different symbols:

filter1_field_name,
filter2_field_name,
filter3_field_name

```
@filter1_field_name = "Region"
@filter2_field_name = "Country"
@filter3_field_name = "City"

SELECT_STATEMENT = "GROUP BY "

numberOfFilters = 3

filter_index = 1
numberOfFilters.times do #Number of iterations 
    filter_field_name = "@filter#{filter_index.to_s}_field_name"
    SELECT_STATEMENT.sub! "GROUP BY", "AND #{filter_field_name.to_sym} GROUP BY"
  filter_index += 1
end

puts SELECT_STATEMENT
```

This results in

> AND @filter1_field_name AND @filter2_field_name AND
>   @filter3_field_name GROUP BY

But the desired result is

> AND Region AND Country AND City GROUP BY

I'm wondering why **filter_field_name.to_sym** is not working (or rather, what I'm doing wrong)?

Comment: The provided answers will do what you want. However, I suggest you consider storing the filters in an array, where item 0 of the array would be the first filter, item 1 would be the 2nd filter and so on.

Comment: `.to_s` can be removed as interpolation (`#{}`) is already doing that implicitly.

Comment: @BrunoFacca - that makes sense indeed. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instance_variable_get` function to get variable value.

Replace the line

```
filter_field_name = "@filter#{filter_index.to_s}_field_name"
```

with

```
filter_field_name = instance_variable_get("@filter#{filter_index.to_s}_field_name")
```

EDIT:

I think you can put the field names into an array and concat the values with `join` method.

```
fields = ['Region','Country','City']
fields.join(' AND ')
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. Learned something else!

Comment: `.to_s` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `instance_variable_get` or `eval`

```
filter_field_name = instance_variable_get("@filter#{filter_index.to_s}_field_name")
```

or

```
filter_field_name = eval("@filter#{filter_index.to_s}_field_name")
```